# AES256-GCM compatibility: Encrypt in Go, decrypt in Python

Tags: python, go, encryption, aes-gcm

While interfacing to the MinIO admin API, I am stuck decrypting the AES256-GCM payload generated by the server. The MinIO server is written in Go, my client app is in Python. While digging into it and testing I discovered that I am not able to create the same ciphertext although I am passing the very same key and nonce (IV).

This is the MinIO code from [`encrypt.go`](https://github.com/minio/madmin-go/blob/b5ea97a17d4e5ec8458cbc3a2962ef5e0729e516/encrypt.go#L38) in [`madmin-go`](https://github.com/minio/madmin-go), instrumented with some `Fprintf` to extract the secrets:

```golang
func EncryptData(password string, data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    salt := sioutil.MustRandom(32)

    var (
        id     byte
        err    error
        stream *sio.Stream
    )
    if FIPSEnabled() {
        key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), salt, pbkdf2Cost, 32, sha256.New)
        stream, err = sio.AES_256_GCM.Stream(key)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        id = pbkdf2AESGCM
    } else {
        key := argon2.IDKey([]byte(password), salt, argon2idTime, argon2idMemory, argon2idThreads, 32)
        if sioutil.NativeAES() {
            stream, err = sio.AES_256_GCM.Stream(key)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            id = argon2idAESGCM
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Key:\n%s\n", hex.Dump([]byte(key)))
            } else {
            stream, err = sio.ChaCha20Poly1305.Stream(key)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            id = argon2idChaCHa20Poly1305
        }
    }

    nonce := sioutil.MustRandom(stream.NonceSize())

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Id:\n%d\n", id)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Password:\n%s\n", hex.Dump([]byte(password)))
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Salt:\n%s\n", hex.Dump([]byte(salt)))
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Nonce:\n%s\n", hex.Dump([]byte(nonce)))

    // ciphertext = salt || AEAD ID | nonce | encrypted data
    cLen := int64(len(salt)+1+len(nonce)+len(data)) + stream.Overhead(int64(len(data)))
    ciphertext := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, cLen)) // pre-alloc correct length

    // Prefix the ciphertext with salt, AEAD ID and nonce
    ciphertext.Write(salt)
    ciphertext.WriteByte(id)
    ciphertext.Write(nonce)

    w := stream.EncryptWriter(ciphertext, nonce, nil)
    if _, err = w.Write(data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = w.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Plain text data:\n%s\n", hex.Dump(data))
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Ciphertext:\n%s\n", hex.Dump(ciphertext.Bytes()))
    return ciphertext.Bytes(), nil
}
```

An `id` of `0` means `argon2idAESGCM`.

This is the result for an example request:

```
Key:
00000000  b9 6b 3a 5a 77 37 94 67  ae b8 9a 06 63 78 cb 87  |.k:Zw7.g....cx..|
00000010  11 4d 54 cd e5 2b 2f 40  f1 af 30 29 fa ad 78 6d  |.MT..+/@..0)..xm|

Id:
0
Password:
00000000  6d 69 6e 69 6f 73 74 6f  72 61 67 65              |miniostorage|

Salt:
00000000  d0 82 60 d8 2d d4 d0 c0  24 45 c6 09 0e 19 38 54  |..`.-...$E....8T|
00000010  88 a1 1b 8d aa 9c 43 3c  81 e9 91 04 12 d3 41 a4  |......C<......A.|

Nonce:
00000000  10 9e 23 ff bb 12 97 0a                           |..#.....|

Plain text data:
00000000  7b 22 66 6f 6f 75 73 65  72 22 3a 7b 22 73 74 61  |{"foouser":{"sta|
00000010  74 75 73 22 3a 22 65 6e  61 62 6c 65 64 22 7d 7d  |tus":"enabled"}}|

Ciphertext:
00000000  d0 82 60 d8 2d d4 d0 c0  24 45 c6 09 0e 19 38 54  |..`.-...$E....8T|
00000010  88 a1 1b 8d aa 9c 43 3c  81 e9 91 04 12 d3 41 a4  |......C<......A.|
00000020  00 10 9e 23 ff bb 12 97  0a a0 6c ff 5c 9c ad 03  |...#......l.\...|
00000030  8a 2f 42 6b 06 cf 8c 28  b0 13 e7 2c df 5f 28 96  |./Bk...(...,._(.|
00000040  1c cb 1f 93 52 58 8b 97  14 8a 8b 44 72 f5 39 61  |....RX.....Dr.9a|
00000050  70 01 dd 12 bb 1c c6 ad  4f                       |p.......O|
```

All attempts to decrypt this ciphertext with Python (3.6.9) failed. Even worse, for the same input data the Python code computes a different ciphertext:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import hexdump
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

key = bytes.fromhex(
    "b9 6b 3a 5a 77 37 94 67  ae b8 9a 06 63 78 cb 87 "
    "11 4d 54 cd e5 2b 2f 40  f1 af 30 29 fa ad 78 6d "
)

nonce = bytes.fromhex(
    "10 9e 23 ff bb 12 97 0a"
)

# plaintext = '{"foouser":{"status":"enabled"}}'
plaintext = bytes.fromhex(
    "7b 22 66 6f 6f 75 73 65  72 22 3a 7b 22 73 74 61 "
    "74 75 73 22 3a 22 65 6e  61 62 6c 65 64 22 7d 7d"
)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(plaintext)

print("ciphertext:")
hexdump.hexdump(ciphertext)

print("tag:")
hexdump.hexdump(tag)
```

The ciphertext computed by Python is

```
ciphertext:
00000000: CC 1C AC BE C2 FF 4A 33  00 23 55 0F 7A E8 88 51  ......J3.#U.z..Q
00000010: 95 93 7A BF 29 2A BE CC  4C 69 A3 78 D3 7D BC 97  ..z.)*..Li.x.}..
tag:
00000000: 41 8E C7 87 1E C0 CE 87  EE CC 7D 01 30 87 A6 C1  A.........}.0...
```

which clearly does not match `a0 6c ff 5c …`.

What am I missing?

(Just for completeness: Deriving the key via Argon2id in Python works fine. It is really the AES operations that produce different results.)

Comment: You have to dig into this Stream thing too. That's not part of Go's standard library. It doesn't support streaming in GCM mode, so that's something home brewn. A 64 bit nonce size is also unusual; 96 bits is standard for GCM. Double check the Python API to make sure that this doesn't require something special to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. According to the [PyCrpytodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html?highlight=aes.new#Crypto.Cipher.AES.new) docs, the nonce length has no restrictions for mode `MODE_GCM`.

Comment: My advice would be to double check endianness, I don't see any of your code actually verify the endianness of the output. Maybe Go's library uses BigEndian and Python' library uses LittleEndian.. You'll have to ensure that's correct.. I've had similar issues where that has been the clear case.